# Payments implementation for PlayN Android Game

Tags: android, payment, playn

I'm using PlayN engine to create a game, and I want to use payments functional to sell game content using Google Wallet.

In [payments-demo sample](https://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/#git/paymentsdemo) I didn't find any part for Android, and in [PlatformStatus](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/PlatformStatus) there is no payments functional too.

I'm just interested,
whether is support payments in Android?
how to use it, is there any code examples?